# Why C# does not have restriction for 'Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor'

Tags: java, c#

I am little confused about constructor calling inside from constructor in java and c#.

When calling another constructor from default constructor other than first statement Java shows error

> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

...but C# allows constructor call from any statement of the constructor.

Can someone clear this why c# does allow to call another constructor from any line of the statement in the default constructor?

**Java:**

```
public class A { 
    A()
    {     
        // this(1);// ->> works fine if written here
        System.out.println("1");
        this(1);  //Error: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
    }
    A(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
public class A { 
    public A()
    {     
        Console.WriteLine("Default constructor called");
        new A(1);  
    }
    public A(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parametrised constructor called");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do that in Java too if you change it from `this(1)` to `new A(1)`.

Comment: Your C# code doesn't do what you think it does. It just creates a *second* instance of `A`.

Comment: The C# equivalent of your code would be `public A() : this(1) { ... }` - and you can't have an intervening statement.

Comment: even with this question starting with a false premise, I think is worth to keep it open since it can clarify this situation for other people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two code segments are not equivalent. You are looking for `this(1)` in C# too (or `base(1)` which can be compared to `super(1)` in Java).

You are now constructing a new object inside your constructor, which gets out of scope immediately after creating it, since you are not assigning it.

C# will give the same error if you call `this(1)` inside your constructor body, so yes, they both work the same way. In C#, you can't even have the call to `this(1)` anywhere inside the constructor. It should be appended like this:

```
public A() : this(1)
{ }
```

Answer (score 8):

Your two code examples are not the same!
For C# it should be:

```
public class A
{ 
    public A() : this(1)
    {     
        Console.WriteLine("Default constructor called");
    }
    public A(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parametrised constructor called");
    }
}
```

In your example you are just creating a second instance of `A`. This would also work in Java.